# Replacing Slashes in JSON URL Data

Tags: json, node.js, express, formatting

I want to replace **"\\" to "/"** in **productImage** path, my code as below I used **replace method** but didn't work, waiting for your help thank you

```
const response = {
    count: docs.length,
    products: docs.map(doc => {
        return {
            name: doc.name,
            price: doc.price,
            productImage: doc.productImage,
            _id: doc._id,
            request: {
                type: "GET",
                url: url + "/products/" + doc._id
            }
        };
    })
};
```

My JSON Output

```
{
    "name": " Sample Product",
    "price": 45,
    "productImage": "uploads\\2018-05-02T09-12-59.937Zahmet.jpg",
    "_id": "5ae9811be170eb0a78500088",
    "request": {
        "type": "GET",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/products/5ae9811be170eb0a78500088"
    }
},
```

Comment: Can you add the code which you are using to replace "\\"?

Comment: I already added, look JSON output ```"productImage": "uploads\\2018-05-02T09-12-59.937Zahmet.jpg",```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split that value by `\\`, you'll get an array, join that array with `/`

```js
var obj = {
    "name": " Sample Product",
    "price": 45,
    "productImage": "uploads\\2018-05-02T09-12-59.937Zahmet.jpg",
    "_id": "5ae9811be170eb0a78500088",
    "request": {
        "type": "GET",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/products/5ae9811be170eb0a78500088"
    }
}

obj.productImage = obj.productImage.split("\\").join("/");


console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Glad to know if that was helpful :)